# spring framework security @preauthorize annotation not working in osgi

Tags: spring-security, osgi, eclipse-virgo

I am using osgi with spring annotations based config. (using virgo to deploy the app)
@preauthorize annotations on the method impl are not working. 
It is allowing the user to access it despite not having the role.

If I put the same annotations on interface, it throws AccessDenied exception for all the users. 
Exception:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied 
 252881 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] ERROR c.w.HomeController  - handleAccessDeniedException####Access is denied 
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:71) 
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:203
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) 
    at $Proxy421.save(Unknown Source) 
    at c.w.controllers.HomeController.home(HomeController.java:125) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapte
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
```

This is my config:

```
  <bean id="expressionHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="aclPermissionEvaluator"/>
  </bean>
  <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" run-as-manager-ref="runAsManager"
    secured-annotations="enabled">
    <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
  </global-method-security>
```

I am using spring-security 3.0.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used @Preauthorize annotations in one bundle and defined global-method-security in another bundle 
The issue got fixed after moving it to the same bundle.